# Tracking File in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to track files specific to a user using my service in AWS. What happens is that the file is uploaded to S3, from there a lambda function is called, it goes to another S3 bucket. Afterwards it goes to EC2 and finally it ends up in ElastiCache. At each of these services, there are various checks that are performed on the file (ie it is checking if it is the right format). I want a user to see what checks have failed.

Are there any services, AWS or others, that can essentially log/track files? I have already looked into AWS CloudTrail (which takes about 15 minutes to receive the log) and loggers in Python.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to need to implement something yourself, like a database with a record for each file that you update during each step of the process. DynamoDB might be a good database to use for this.

There is nothing built into AWS that will track what happens with the file once you copy it into an EC2 instance.